# How do I embed views in node template

Tags: views, theming, 8

Please how can I embed a view in a node template like `node--blog--full.html.twig`.

I have configured an about-the-author views to be embedded in full mode of blog content type using `views-embed-view()`, but it doesn't work. I have enabled the "Allow embedded displays" from views settings and followed a few tips online, but none seems to work.

1. Is there a better way to embed views in D8 node template?
2. How can I use `views-embed-view` correctly in D8?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be sure, are you calling `views-embed-view()`, or `views_embed_view()` (Note the dashes/underscores). The second version (`views_embed_view()` is the correct one).

Also, how do you call the function? Which parameters do you pass?

As per [this page](http://dropbucket.org/node/6605), the correct way of embedding a view is 1 of the following ways.

**Option 1:**

```
// Get the embeded view and render it.
drupal_render(views_embed_view('VIEW_NAME', 'DISPLAY_ID'));
```

**Option 2**

```
// Get the embeded view and render it.
\Drupal::service('renderer')->render(views_embed_view('VIEW_NAME', 'DISPLAY_ID'));
```

In this example you will have to replace `VIEW_NAME` with the machine name of your view, and the `DISPLAY_ID` should be replaced with the ID of the display you want to use (Or can be omitted to use the default display).

*Also note that the second option is the better one, since the drupal_render function is deprecated, and will be removed before Drupal 9.0.0 ([More info](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render/8)).*

Comment: **Martie**, where should I place the solution you provided, in `node template` or `.theme file`. If in `.html.twig file`, should it be wrapped in `{{}}` ?

Comment: @chikaodili I didn't work that much with Drupal 8 yet myself, but I would most likely place this kind of logic in a preprocess function for your node, then add it to the variables. eg. `$variables['my_embedded_view']`. In your twig template you should be able to call `{{ my_embedded_view }}` to display the view.

Comment: I know we are all learning D8 together, its still not very clear, but we have to continue to try.

Comment: based on your directions this is what I have done. I added this to `.theme file` : `function THEMENAME_preprocess_node(&$variables){
  
 $variables['about_author'] = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render(views_embed_view('about_the_author', 'block'));

 }`. Then places `{{about_author}}` in the node template. However am getting this error `Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in THEMENAME_preprocess_node() (line 70 of themes/custom/THEMENAME/THEMENAME.theme).

Comment: @chikaodili I'm guessing that's caused by passing the `views_embed_view()` directly in the `render()` function. Try changing it to somethign like
`$about_author_view = views_embed_view('about_the_author', 'block'); 
\Drupal::service('renderer')->render($about_author_view);`

Comment: errors are gone but nothing is displaying. I changed display_id to 'default' yet no result.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with how template debugging works in Drupal 8 (or with twig), but what kind of output do you get when dumping the contents of either `variables` or `about_author`?

Also, I was reading up a bit on the `views_embed_view()` function, and apparently you're not the only one having issues with this. someone created an extension for twig as a new module, which allows you to call the `views_embed_view()` function in your twig template directly. Might be worth checking the module out: https://www.drupal.org/project/tve

Comment: **Martie**, both your guide and the tve module solves this problem. I saw that permission was blocking the view. Since all dummy contents were created by user1, anonymous users cannot view the author details. i have created other nodes using other user accounts and it works fine. Great Job! thanks

Comment: @chikaodili Aaaah, allright. Glad to hear everything works fine now!